# Can somebody help me choose relevant literature

Tags: reference-request, descartes, rationalism, secondary-literature

I want to excuse myself beforehand if this is an inappropriate question on this forum.
I'm just starting studying and I need literature for my little paperwork in a philosophy seminar. The main line of the topic is "clear and distinct ideas in Descartes philosophy"
I thought that maybe "Meditations on first philosophy" is go to primary source , but I don't know any secondary literature. Can somebody maybe recommend primary and secondary literature.
If this isn't the forum to ask about this , could somebody maybe tell me what is ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

[SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/) and [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/rene-descartes/) are the standard goto places for philosophy material.

[Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Rene-Descartes) can also be good.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) is of course there for starters but spotty and not always reliable

Comment: I lost faith in Britannica.

Answer (score 0):

Descartes, René. "The Philosophical Writings of Descartes", translated by John Cottingham, Robert Stoothoff, and Dugald Murdoch.

Cottingham, John. "Descartes".

Kenny, Anthony. "Descartes: A Study of His Philosophy".

Williams, Bernard. "Descartes: The Project of Pure Enquiry".

Garber, Daniel. "Descartes Embodied: Reading Cartesian Philosophy through Cartesian Science".

Newman, Lex. "The Carmenesque Metaphysics of Descartes: The Late Scholastic Origins of Modern Philosophy".

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to say, that the book by Kenny and Cottingham helped me a lot. Thank you again :) .